# django-ckeditor_uploader5.0.3 don't work in my server

Tags: django, python-3.x, ckeditor

I have installed django-1.9.8 and django-ckeditor-5.0.3 recently,and I have read the document in https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor. In my computer,I use uwsgi and nginx to run my django-project.Fortunately，I use richtextuploaderfield and successfully upload files.But when I rsync my projects to my server,and my server also have installed django-1.9.8 and django-ckeditor-5.0.3.I run "./manage.py collectstatic".Howerver when I entered django-admin in my server,I click the "upload to server" button in ckeditor,the status bar shows "uploading",then it shows as images below.I don't know why it is.Please help me.Thank you all the same!

[ckeditor-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ1mQ.png)

Comment: Could you provide an English translation of the error message?

Comment: Thank you,There is no error message.I select the file to upload,and I click the "upload to server" button,and then I fileUploadField became my homepage,And I can not successfully upload file.

Answer (score 0):

Standard:

1. Check group and allow write permission
2. check static path for web
3. check media path
4. Settings.py template string 'django.template.context_processors.static'

Comment: Thank you!I set 777 for the directory  and the admin user is superuser.static and media path is set by Nginx

Comment: Thank you very much,I fixed it

Comment: Fix my comment: 755 for folders, 666 for files, user group default for web server www-data (example:  chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/myproj/ ) or use run group uwsgi server/nginx server